# Rails 5: Event system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, associations

I'm making an event system. I have a model Event, and each event will have files, reports, providers and so on.

Here is my routes today:

```
  scope 'app', :module => "app" do
    resources :events, :roteiros, 
              :convidados, :lista_convidados,
              :orcamentos, :orcamento_items, :providers, 
              :providers_items, :reports, :reports_items,
              :modelos, :modelos_items, :arquivos, :arquivos_items   
    end
```

I'm looking for the best way to the others models, when edited or create new data, the new information is associated with the Event model, then each event will have the information associated with it.

I think it should be something like that:

```
scope 'app', :module => "app" do
    resources :events do

              :roteiros, 
              :convidados, :lista_convidados,
              :orcamentos, :orcamento_items, :providers, 
              :providers_items, :reports, :reports_items,
              :modelos, :modelos_items, :arquivos, :arquivos_items

    end
end
```

Then the url would look like `/app/events/event-name/providers`

I would still need to get the event id so I can associate a new record with a specific event

All models already have the `event_id` value to association

Thank you for your help.

**UPDATE**

> Current routes:

```
  scope 'app', :module => "app" do
    resources :events do
      resources :arquivos, 
                :arquivos_items,
                :convidados, 
                :lista_convidados,
                :modelos, 
                :modelos_items, 
                :orcamento_items, 
                :orcamentos, 
                :providers, 
                :providers_items, 
                :reports, 
                :reports_items,
                :roteiros, shallow: true
    end

    resources :todo_lists do
      member do
        patch :complete
      end

      resources :todo_items do
        member do
          patch :complete
        end
      end
    end


  end
```

> Controller

```
module App
  class OrcamentosController < SuperAppController
    before_action :set_orcamento, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    # GET /orcamentos
    # GET /orcamentos.json
    def index
      @orcamentos = Orcamento.all
      @orcamento = Orcamento.new
      @orcamento_item = OrcamentoItem.new
    end

    # GET /orcamentos/1
    # GET /orcamentos/1.json
    def show
    end

    # GET /orcamentos/new
    def new
      @orcamento = Orcamento.new
    end

    # GET /orcamentos/1/edit
    def edit
    end

    # POST /orcamentos
    # POST /orcamentos.json
    def create
      @orcamento = Orcamento.new(orcamento_params)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @orcamento.save
          format.html { redirect_to orcamentos_path, notice: 'Orcamento inserido.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @orcamento }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @orcamento.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /orcamentos/1
    # PATCH/PUT /orcamentos/1.json
    def update
      respond_to do |format|
        if @orcamento.update(orcamento_params)
          format.html { redirect_to orcamentos_path, notice: 'Orcamento atualizado.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @orcamento }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @orcamento.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    # DELETE /orcamentos/1
    # DELETE /orcamentos/1.json
    def destroy
      @orcamento.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to orcamentos_url, notice: 'Orcamento removido.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end

    private
      # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
      def set_orcamento
        @event = Event.friendly.find(params[:id])
        @orcamento = Orcamento.find(params[:id])
      end

      # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
      def orcamento_params
        params.require(:orcamento).permit(:title, orcamento_items_attributes: [:id, :desc, :estimado, :real, :pago, :pendente, :vencimento, :orcamento_id, :venc, :_destroy])
      end
  end
end
```

> URL test

```
/app/events/teste-de-evento/orcamentos
```

> Partial

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/app/todo_lists">
      <div class="itemMenu <%= 'active' if controller_name == 'todo_lists' %>">CHECKLIST</div>
    </a></li>
  <li><a href="<%= event_orcamentos_url(@event) %>">
      <div class="itemMenu <%= 'active' if controller_name == 'orcamentos' %>">ORÇAMENTO</div>
    </a></li>
  <li><a href="/app/lista_convidados">
      <div class="itemMenu <%= 'active' if controller_name == 'lista_convidados' %>">CONVIDADOS</div>
    </a></li>
  <li><a href="">
      <div class="itemMenu">AGENDA</div>
    </a></li>
  <li><a href="/app/providers/">
      <div class="itemMenu <%= 'active' if controller_name == 'providers' %>">FORNECEDORES</div>
    </a></li>
  <li><a href="/app/roteiros/">
      <div class="itemMenu <%= 'active' if controller_name == 'roteiros' %>">ROTEIROS</div>
    </a></li>
  <li><a href="/app/arquivos">
      <div class="itemMenu <%= 'active' if controller_name == 'arquivos' %>">ARQUIVOS</div>
    </a></li>
  <li><a href="/app/reports/">
      <div class="itemMenu <%= 'active' if controller_name == 'reports' %>">RELATÓRIOS</div>
    </a></li>
</ul>
```

> View

```
<section id="content">
    <section class="row wrapContent">
      <header class="sHeaderPagina column large-12 medium-12 small-12">
        <a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">
          <h2 class="backMenu"><div class="arrow"></div>Inicial</h2>
        </a>
        <!-- END BACK MENU -->

        <nav id="sMenuEventos">
          <%= render 'sharedApp/navegacao' %>

          <div class="acoesGerenciar">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="">
                  <div class="AddUser"></div>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a href="">
                  <div class="btPDF"></div>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a href="/app/events/teste-evento/edit">
                  <div class="btConfigs"></div>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- END NAV EVENTOS -->

        <div class="row">
          <div class="infoWidget column large-3 medium-6 small-12">
            <div class="boxInfo">
              <h3>Custo Estimado</h3>
              <h2>R$ 0,00</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- END WIDGET -->
          <div class="infoWidget column large-3 medium-6 small-12">
            <div class="boxInfo">
              <h3>Custo Real</h3>
              <h2>R$ 0,00</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- END WIDGET -->
          <div class="infoWidget column large-3 medium-6 small-12">
            <div class="boxInfo">
              <h3>Valor Pago</h3>
              <h2>R$ 0,00</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- END WIDGET -->
          <div class="infoWidget column large-3 medium-6 small-12">
            <div class="boxInfo">
              <h3>Custo Pendente</h3>
              <h2>R$ 0,00</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- END WIDGET -->
        </div>

      </header>
      <!-- END HEADER -->

      <a id="addItemBt" href="javascript:;"><span class="btAdd">+</span></a>

<% if @orcamentos.any? 
        @orcamentos.each do |orcamento| %>
      <article class="sTable sTableActive column large-12 medium-12 small-12">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="openTable">
          <header>
            <h3><%= orcamento.title %></h3>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
          </header>
        </a>

        <div class="wrapTable ">
          <table class="hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th width="200">Descrição</th>
                <th>Custo Estimado</th>
                <th width="150">Custo Real</th>
                <th width="150">Valor Pago</th>
                <th width="150">Valor Pendente</th>
                <th width="150">Próximo Vencimento</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

              <% orcamento.orcamento_items.each do |o| %>
                <tr>
                  <td><%= o.desc %></td>
                  <td>R$ <%= o.estimado %></td>
                  <td class="blue">R$ <%= o.real %></td>
                  <td>R$ <%= o.pago %></td>
                  <td>R$ <%= o.pendente %></td>
                  <td>
                    <%= o.vencimento %>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              <% end %>

              <tr>
                <%#= form_for(new_convidado_path) do |f| %>
                <%= form_for @orcamento_item, :url => { :controller => "orcamento_items", :action => "create" }, :html => {:method => :post} do |f| %>
                  <td>
                    <%= f.hidden_field :orcamento_id, value: orcamento.id, required: true %>

                    <%= f.telephone_field :desc, placeholder: "Descrição", required: true %>
                  </td>

                  <td>
                    <%= f.telephone_field :estimado, placeholder: "Estimado", required: true, class: "valor" %>
                  </td>

                  <td>
                    <%= f.telephone_field :real, placeholder: "Real", required: true, class: "valor" %>
                  </td>

                  <td>
                    <%= f.telephone_field :pago, placeholder: "Pago", required: true, class: "valor" %>

                  </td>

                  <td>
                    <%= f.telephone_field :pendente, placeholder: "Pendente", required: true, class: "valor" %>
                  </td>


                  <td>
                    <%= f.text_field :vencimento, placeholder: "Vencimento", required: true, class: "data" %>
                    <%= f.submit "+", class: "plusSubmit" %>
                  </td>

                <% end %>
              </tr>

              <tr class="total">
                <td class="subtotal">Sub-total</td>
                <td>R$ 0.000</td>
                <td class="blue">R$ 0.000</td>
                <td>R$ 0.000</td>
                <td>R$ 0.000</td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>

          <ul class="acoes">
            <% orcamento.orcamento_items.each do |c| %>
              <li>
                  <div class="btActions"></div>
                  <div class="opcoesCadastro">
                    <a href="">
                      <div class="editar"></div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="">
                      <div class="excluir"></div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
              </li>
              <!-- END ITEM -->
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </article>
      <!-- END LISTA -->
<% end else %>
  <article class="sTable sTableSelect sTableActive column large-12 medium-12 small-12">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="openTable">
          <header>
            <h3>Nenhuma orçamento ainda</h3>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
          </header>
        </a>
  </article>
<% end %>






    </section>
  </section>
<!-- ========================== END CONTENT -->


  <section class="modal modalCadastro" style="display: none;">
    <section class="boxModal centerModal">
      <header>
        <h2>Adicionar Tabela de Orçamento</h2>
        <a class="fecharBt fecharModal" href="javascript:;"><img src="./assets/images/icons/fechar.png" alt="" class="fechar"></a>
      </header>

      <%= form_with(model: @orcamento, local: true, html: { class: "row" }) do |f| %>
        <div class="inputFormCadastro">
          <label for="">Nome da lista</label>
          <%= f.text_field :title, required: true %>
        </div>
        <!-- END ITEM -->

        <h3 class="titleBoxExtras">Adicionar Orçamento</h3>
        <div id='boxCamposExtras'>
          <%= f.fields_for :orcamento_items do |task| %>
            <%= render 'orcamento_items_fields', :f => task %>
          <% end %>
          <div class='links'>
            <%= link_to_add_association 'adicionar orçamento', f, :orcamento_items %>
          </div>
        </div>



        <div class="botoes">
          <%= f.submit "CRIAR", class: "botao" %>
          <a href="#" class="btLink fecharModal">CANCELAR</a>
        </div>
      <% end %>

    </section>
  </section>
  <!-- END MODAL -->
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need `resources` in front of your nested items. Something like:

```
scope 'app', :module => "app" do
  resources :events do
    resources :roteiros, 
              :convidados, :lista_convidados,
              :orcamentos, :orcamento_items, :providers, 
              :providers_items, :reports, :reports_items,
              :modelos, :modelos_items, :arquivos, :arquivos_items
  end
end
```

Which, when you run `rake routes` in the console, will give you something like:

```
    event_roteiros GET    /app/events/:event_id/roteiros(.:format)              app/roteiros#index
                   POST   /app/events/:event_id/roteiros(.:format)              app/roteiros#create
 new_event_roteiro GET    /app/events/:event_id/roteiros/new(.:format)          app/roteiros#new
edit_event_roteiro GET    /app/events/:event_id/roteiros/:id/edit(.:format)     app/roteiros#edit
     event_roteiro GET    /app/events/:event_id/roteiros/:id(.:format)          app/roteiros#show
                   PATCH  /app/events/:event_id/roteiros/:id(.:format)          app/roteiros#update
                   PUT    /app/events/:event_id/roteiros/:id(.:format)          app/roteiros#update
                   DELETE /app/events/:event_id/roteiros/:id(.:format)          app/roteiros#destroy

                   ... omitting a bunch of routes ...

            events GET    /app/events(.:format)                                 app/events#index
                   POST   /app/events(.:format)                                 app/events#create
         new_event GET    /app/events/new(.:format)                             app/events#new
        edit_event GET    /app/events/:id/edit(.:format)                        app/events#edit
             event GET    /app/events/:id(.:format)                             app/events#show
                   PATCH  /app/events/:id(.:format)                             app/events#update
                   PUT    /app/events/:id(.:format)                             app/events#update
                   DELETE /app/events/:id(.:format)                             app/events#destroy
```

As you can see, that will cause everything to be namespaced under `app`. That means your controllers would need to look like:

```
class App::RoteirosController < ApplicationController 
  ...
end
```

And that file would be under:

```
app
 |- controllers
 |   |- app
 |   |   |- roteiros_controller.rb
```

Which I suspect you don't want. So, it should be more like:

```
resources :events do
  resources :roteiros, 
            :convidados, :lista_convidados,
            :orcamentos, :orcamento_items, :providers, 
            :providers_items, :reports, :reports_items,
            :modelos, :modelos_items, :arquivos, :arquivos_items
end
```

As discussed in the [docs in section 2.7.2 Shallow Nesting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), you might consider doing something like:

```
resources :events do
  resources :arquivos, 
            :arquivos_items,
            :convidados, 
            :lista_convidados,
            :modelos, 
            :modelos_items, 
            :orcamento_items, 
            :orcamentos, 
            :providers, 
            :providers_items, 
            :reports, 
            :reports_items,
            :roteiros, 
            shallow: true
end
```

In which case, you'll get something like:

```
    event_arquivos GET    /events/:event_id/arquivos(.:format)              arquivos#index
                   POST   /events/:event_id/arquivos(.:format)              arquivos#create
 new_event_arquivo GET    /events/:event_id/arquivos/new(.:format)          arquivos#new
      edit_arquivo GET    /arquivos/:id/edit(.:format)                      arquivos#edit
           arquivo GET    /arquivos/:id(.:format)                           arquivos#show
                   PATCH  /arquivos/:id(.:format)                           arquivos#update
                   PUT    /arquivos/:id(.:format)                           arquivos#update
                   DELETE /arquivos/:id(.:format)                           arquivos#destroy

                   ... omitting a bunch of routes ...

            events GET    /events(.:format)                                 events#index
                   POST   /events(.:format)                                 events#create
         new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)                             events#new
        edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)                        events#edit
             event GET    /events/:id(.:format)                             events#show
                   PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)                             events#update
                   PUT    /events/:id(.:format)                             events#update
                   DELETE /events/:id(.:format)                             events#destroy
```

According to your example, however, it looks like you want to use `:event_name` as the identifier instead of `:event_id`. In which case, you would do:

```
resources :events, param: :name do
  resources :arquivos, 
            :arquivos_items,
            :convidados, 
            :lista_convidados,
            :modelos, 
            :modelos_items, 
            :orcamento_items, 
            :orcamentos, 
            :providers, 
            :providers_items, 
            :reports, 
            :reports_items,
            :roteiros, 
            shallow: true
end
```

Which will give you:

```
    event_arquivos GET    /events/:event_name/arquivos(.:format)            arquivos#index
                   POST   /events/:event_name/arquivos(.:format)            arquivos#create
 new_event_arquivo GET    /events/:event_name/arquivos/new(.:format)        arquivos#new
      edit_arquivo GET    /arquivos/:id/edit(.:format)                      arquivos#edit
           arquivo GET    /arquivos/:id(.:format)                           arquivos#show
                   PATCH  /arquivos/:id(.:format)                           arquivos#update
                   PUT    /arquivos/:id(.:format)                           arquivos#update
                   DELETE /arquivos/:id(.:format)                           arquivos#destroy

                   ... omitting a bunch of routes ...

            events GET    /events(.:format)                                 events#index
                   POST   /events(.:format)                                 events#create
         new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)                             events#new
        edit_event GET    /events/:name/edit(.:format)                      events#edit
             event GET    /events/:name(.:format)                           events#show
                   PATCH  /events/:name(.:format)                           events#update
                   PUT    /events/:name(.:format)                           events#update
                   DELETE /events/:name(.:format)                           events#destroy
```

Which I think is what you're looking for.

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for your help. How routes work as you said. But when adding the links to the items, type event_orcamentos_url I get the error: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"app/orcamentos", :id=>"teste-de-evento"}, missing required keys: [:event_id]. Should I change someting in the controllers to get the id of event?

Comment: My controller its getting just the id of the especific items, like def set_orcamento
        @orcamento = Orcamento.find(params[:id])
      end

Comment: I tried to use event_orcamentos_url(@event) and it works, but when I go to link I get No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"app/orcamentos", :event_id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:event_id] in the path: <%= event_orcamentos_url(@event) %>

Comment: You should probably use `event_orcamentos_path(@event)`. Then, you need to make sure that your `@event` instance is set in your controller action. It looks like you're probably not setting `@event` which is why you're getting `:event_id=>nil`.

Comment: Also, you need to decide if you're going to use `:id` or `:name` as your identifier. As you can see here: `No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"app/orcamentos", :id=>"teste-de-evento"}`, it looks like you're trying to use the `name` as the `id`.

Comment: I'm using id, because I'm already using frindly_id gem. I tried set parammters `@event = Event.friendly.find(params[:id])`
        `@orcamento = Orcamento.find(params[:id])` and then `{event_orcamentos_url(@event)`, but I still get the error: `{:action=>"index", :controller=>"app/orcamentos", :event_id=>nil}`

Comment: I'm also tried put on the index funcion: `@event = Event.friendly.find(params[:id])` but I get `Couldn't find Event without an ID`

Comment: Can you add your current `routes.rb`, your relevant controller action, your partial, and console output to your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174901/discussion-between-jvillian-and-fernando-aureliano).